# gitlab-ctl reconfigure error when creating user/group on initial install

Tags: linux, redhat, git, gitlab, rhel7

I'm trying to run Gitlab CE on RHEL 7.2 (Maipo).  I've completed the Gitlab install.  However I'm unable to run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.  The error, environment details and what I've tried is outlined below.  Does anyone know what I'm missing or doing wrong?

### Error

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'user[Webserver user and group]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '6'
---- Begin output of ["usermod", "-s", "/bin/false", "-d", "/var/opt/gitlab/nginx", "gitlab-www"] ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: usermod: user 'gitlab-www' does not exist in /etc/passwd
---- End output of ["usermod", "-s", "/bin/false", "-d", "/var/opt/gitlab/nginx", "gitlab-www"] ----
Ran ["usermod", "-s", "/bin/false", "-d", "/var/opt/gitlab/nginx", "gitlab-www"] returned 6
```

### Environment

RHEL 7.2 (Maipo), Chef Client, version 12.12.15 (taken for the `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` output)

### What I've tried

- Followed install steps [here](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#centos7) for RHEL 7.
- Manually add the gitlab-www user:  When executing this `sudo useradd -s /bin/false -d /var/opt/gitlab/nginx gitlab-www` I get the error `useradd: user 'gitlab-www' already exists`.  However I verified a record for gitlab-www doesn't exist in /etc/passwd.
- Renamed users in gitlab.rb:  I renamed the following users in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb [git, gitlab-www, git-redis, and gitlab-psql].  That does allow me to run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` successfully but this seems like a super hack and I don't know what the impact is to the Gitlab installation.  I had to rename all those users because after renaming gitlab-www I would get the same error with the user git, then git-redis and so on.

Answer (score 0):

When a user is created properly, it gets added to two files - `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. The former contains info about the home directory, login shell etc; the latter contains the encrypted password for the user.

From your description, I should guess that the user exists in `/etc/shadow` but not in `/etc/passwd`.

The simplest solution is to either edit `/etc/shadow` (using sudo) and remove the line that looks something like

```
gitlab-www:!!:12345::::::
```

Another possibility is to manually add the user to `/etc/passwd`. First, find the UID in the shadow file:

```
[jenny@finch ~]$ sudo grep gitlab-www /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f3
12345
[jenny@finch ~]$ sudo vi + /etc/passwd
```

Then add the following line:

```
 gitlab-www:x:12345:12345:Gitlab WWW user:/var/opt/gitlab/nginx:/bin/false
```

Comment: I don't see the gitlab-www user in /etc/shadow either.  I checked by [sudo cat /etc/shadow].  Looking for the UID in the shadow with the command you suggested outputs nothing.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Stop the gitlab service first **gitlab-ctl stop**
Then do **gitlab-ctl reconfigure**, once its completed, run the command **gitlab-ctl start**